# In Webpack 4, how do I get my import to load before my code?

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to use the following module:

http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

I have installed it using npm install.

Then I import it using:

```
import "bootstrap-fileinput";
```

and then have my code afterwards.

When I look at the code that Webpack bundles, my custom code appears first followed by the `bootstrap-fileinput` library. How do I reverse the order so that the `bootstrap-fileinput` library comes before my code?

Comment: have you checked to see if it is executing first? Webpack has a lot of logic behind so don't only trust on the code that you see.

Comment: Yes I know it’s the wrong order because previously it worked when I loaded the library first using <script></script> tags and then loaded my code second.

Comment: That is weird because webpack follows es modules spec constraint and the code is executed in the order that it is put on the file (it is not wrong, its the spec). That library might need something, or has any different way of importing that requires to be done

Comment: That needs jquery to run, so it is only going to run when jquery is already available in the global scope. Use Provide Plugin